# How to ingest logs in Solr

Tags: indexing, solr, logstash

I have apache logs of my website, which includes the link clicked by user and many other parameters. I need to provide these logs to apache Solr by extracting each term in the logs.

I have read about various options like logstash, loggly, rsyslog. However, for me, it is a little confusing. So, it will be a great help if anyone can guide me with steps or any resources to do the above mentioned task.

Comment: Why solr?  Are you open to alternatives?

Comment: Actually I am working on a project where solr is already being used for different purposes and it makes sense in keeping the system consistent using solr for this task too.